# Load a chrome extension and find current website javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm currently trying to make a chrome extension but I'm a bit lost -_-

I have two questions, my first one is how do I go about seeing if a user is on a certain website and execute the code ?

I have this so far:

```
if(href == "instagram") {
    console.warn("You are on instagram !!")
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

my second question is how do I add a chrome extension, I followed a tutorial but I it does not match what i see on my screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question answer**

As for your first question, "href == " doesn't work, you need `window.location.href` and `match`, like so:

```
if(window.location.href.match("www.instagram") {
    console.warn("You are on instagram !!")
}
```

If you're going to be using this a lot I recommend putting it into a variable like `url = window.location.href`, so then you can just use `url.match`

**Second question answer**

To add your chrome extension, go to chrome://extensions and click "developer mode" in the top right. Then you should see something called "load unpacked" - once you press this locate the folder for your chrome extension and add it.

Comment: thank you very much i appreciate your help

Comment: @curiouscommenter188 no problem, [please accept this as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it has answered your question :)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you are doing `href == "instagram"`. What this does, is compare them directly. But the `href` is actually going to be something like `instagram.com` or `https://instagram.com/something`, so the statement won't work.

You probably want to do

```js
if (window.location.href.includes('instagram') {
    console.log('You are on Instagram!');
}
```

For your second question, it's a longer answer than SO is really meant for. Try taking a look at this: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-install-the-unpacked-extension-in-chrome/

Comment: thank you very much!